# Qt culture-aware QString container classes

Tags: qt, localization

We have a text-analysis application where the text being analyzed can be of any culture (English, Spanish, Thai, Arabic, etc.) Different cultures have different rules for strings: sorting, word breaks, determining which characters are the same, etc.

How do I make Qt container classes culture-aware? For example, if I am using `QMap<QString, int>`, I want the keys to stay sorted based on the rules of a user-specified culture. (The culture is not necessary the same as the host OS.) Likewise, it should consider "duplicates" according to the rules of that culture.

In .Net, all such containers can be [constructed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx) with a culture-aware comparer such as `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`. Is there an equivalent in Qt? If not, what workarounds exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a simple way to do this with a `QMap`. It is possible using `std::map` which has a [constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/map/) that lets you specify a custom comparator.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out, you could use `std::map`, but another option is to create a `LocalizedString` class that has a `QString` conversion operator.  If you then overload less than and friends so that they defer to [localeAwareCompare()](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qstring.html#localeAwareCompare) or a comparison object of your own creation, I think you'll end up with pretty much what you need.

Answer (score 1):

`QString` does have [`localeAwareCompare`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qstring.html#localeAwareCompare) for that purpose. QMap does not take a compare function as template parameter but I think you can use STL map for that.

Comment: I don't think you can specify a particular locale for the localeAwareCompare (it uses the system locale). Plus I need it to be case-insensitive. Looks like the STL map might come to the rescue, combined with some ICU locale algorithms.